# What does environmental factor include?

Tags: terminology, green-chemistry

Does [E-factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_chemistry_metrics#Environmental_(E)_factor) include all of the reagents including catalysts, solvents, and reactants that go into making the product? Further, in the E-factor calculation should all the solvents used in work-up (such as water and ammonia solution) also be included?

$$\text{E-factor} = \frac{\text{total waste}~(\pu{kg})}{\text{product}~(\pu{kg})} = \frac{(\text{total reagents} - \text{product})~(\pu{kg})}{\text{product}~(\pu{kg})}$$

Comment: What is recycled ( like destilled solvents , or purified reagents) or reused ( like catalysts ) cannot be taken as waste.